# Computing power and memory for regression analysis

Tags: power, memory

Does raspberry pi 3 have enough computing power and memory to perform regression analysis?I am making a Coordinate measuring machine prototype for my final year project and I need to perform linear quadratic and beziar curve fitting to measure the geometry of objects.

Comment: What is the computation requirement for "regression analysis"?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly the Raspberry Pi can do regression analysis, but the speed at which it computes is affected by the CPU - for RPi 3B, it is a Quad Core 1.2GHz Broadcom BCM2837 64bit CPU -, the RAM - which in a RPi is 1GB - as well as by what programming language you use, the size of the program, and how well your variables are managed for speed and compactability.

It is certainly doable, but I would prefer a desktop computer for any serious computation.